# CUDA, do i need a newer card? Differences on the 1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 2.1

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda, nvidia

Was looking into some GPU CUDA samples and trying some samples out from Nvidia's pack and also some of the demos in OpenCV. Most of Nvidia's samples run, but OpenCV gives me mostly OpenCV Error: Gpu API call (invalid device symbol).

I have a gts 8800 card, supporting what Nvidia lists as compute capability 1.0. What are the differences and are my errors related to this? Can I run more stuff if I buy a newer card?

Comment: Download the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) and have a read through it. I will give you all the information you need with regards to the various compute capabilities and their differences/improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that OpenCV supports CUDA capabilities from 1.1 and up. Sad, but true...

From OpenCV Makefile:

```
set(CUDA_ARCH_BIN "1.1 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.1(2.0)" 
         CACHE STRING "Specify 'real' GPU architectures to build binaries for, 
         BIN(PTX) format is supported")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use more advanced features if you buy a newer card. You can use the DeviceQuery SDK example to get the compute capability, or you can look it up for many cards. Differences between hardware devices of differing compute capability are listed in appendices of the CUDA Programming Guide and/or the CUDA Best Practices Guide, both of which are available at the same place you get the driver and toolkit... developer.nvidia.com, perhaps.

I don't know whether this is the cause of your specific problem or not; but in general, newer devices can do more than older devices, in many cases.

Comment: I did get it to run after compiling opencv myself. Just need to figure out where those demo sources are so i can try them aslo.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 8800 gtx and i cant use CUDA features with version 1.0. For a correct CUDA detection use:

```
if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda &&
    GpuInvoke.GetCudaEnabledDeviceCount() > 0 &&
    new GpuDevice(GpuInvoke.GetDevice()).CudaComputeCapability.Major > 1)
{  
   //enter code here
}
```